# Editing a prototype method .push() in javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, parameters, prototype

I've never worked with prototype, and maybe I don't even understand how it works, so here I am.

I'm trying to change how **.push()** works in javascript: it adds the parameter as the last element, but I want it to add the parameter **in the first position**.

Here is my non-working guess:

```
    Array.prototype.push() = function(e){
      var x = [e]; 
      return x.concat(this);
    }
```

Sorry for the breathtaking mistakes I probably made :)

**Disclaimer:** I'm just trying to understand how to modify native methods. Why is everybody so scared?

Comment: The built-in `.unshift()` method adds new elements to the start of the array - any reason why you're not using it instead of trying to redefine `.push()`?

Comment: push does not remove last element in the array, it adds new one to the array

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I wanted to say add, not remove. I wasnt focused.

Comment: Regarding your edit, now you say you want it to add the parameter in "the last position", but that's what `.push()` already does (at least, it doesn't overwrite whatever is already in the last position, it appends after it, but...).

Comment: o man i need to sleep more haha sorry.

Comment: you should add an example of before and after look of array

Comment: OK, so again, what's wrong with using the existing `.unshift()` method?

Comment: I ask this because i want to understand how to modify prototype methods

Comment: @JoseLuisDominguezQuintans If you wanted to modify protype method, just look at my answer. You used parenthesis next to push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loose the parenthesis :

```
Array.prototype.push = function(e){
  var x = [e]; 
  this.unshift(e);
}
```

EDIT:

If you don't want to use unshift inside, you can do splice :

```
 Array.prototype.push = function(e){
   var x = [e];   
var y = [];
   for(var j = 0; j< this.length; j++) y[j] = this[j];
   this[0] = x;
   for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) this[i+1] = y[i];
}
```

Comment: I don't think all browsers support overriding native functions.

Comment: @Prajwal Well, I don't think so. Can you please give an example of browser?

Comment: This code will return a new array rather than modifying the array it is called on.

Comment: @binariedM thank but i cant make it work. The console says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" in the line of "this = x.concat..."

Comment: I never seen a scenario where you replace native function. Would this fall under good practice?

Comment: Actually the problem with prev. one was that you can't reassign this.

Comment: thanks @binariedMe but with your solution, deeply, your just using unshift, that im trying to avoid. im trying to edit somehow the array "manually"

Comment: @JoseLuisDominguezQuintans The edit section is using just length property of array which too can be avoided using an undefined check in while loop. Try that.

Comment: You don't need the temporary `y` array, you can slide the existing elements to the right with one loop something like `for(var i = this.length; i > 0; i--) this[i] = this[i-1]`. (With a slight adjustment you can slide the elements over by more than one space, should you want to insert multiple elements at the beginning.)

Comment: @Prajwal in javascript, you can almost hack the entire language, which is a powerful feature, but dangerous. most of the time, if not always, changing on the prototype of the native constructors is considered bad practice (such as editing the `push`) because if your code depend on libraries etc, they expect their push to work like it should, not like how you reimplemented it.

Comment: @Prajwal Its not a bad practice if you have a good reason. Like lets say, I want a log to be triggered whenever someone pushes something to an array.

Answer (score 1):

To add element in first position use `.unshift`. You don't need `prototype` for this.

You don't want to override `.push()` or any other native method.

```js
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
data.unshift(10);

// 10 is first element
console.log(data);
```